# JButton global settings

Tags: java, jbutton

So I have created multiple JButtons in my app. Now I want to modify their design, like, change color, size, style, etc. Is there any way to avoid having to set these things to every JButton separately?

Comment: Create a class that extends JButton that has everything you want (design, color, size, style...), and use that class instead of JButton.

Answer (score 0):

### Custom Class that extends JButton

As already suggested, you can use a custom class that extends `JButton` change the styling of the button there, and then create instances from this custom class.

An example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CustomJButton extends JButton
{
   private Font font = new Font("MS UI Gothic", Font.BOLD, 30);;

   public CustomJButton(String buttonName)
   {
      this.setText(buttonName);
      this.setFont(font);
      this.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
   }
}
```

You then create an instance of this class in your main class like this:

```
.
.
  CustomJButton button = new CustomJButton("Click Me");
.
.
```

And you have as a result:

[image]

### Alternative solution

You can use the [`Font`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) object to declare "global" settings.

An example:

```
Font font = new Font("MS UI Gothic", Font.BOLD, 30);
```

And lets assume that you have the following `jButtons`: `jButton1`, `jButton2`:

```
jButton1.setFont(font);
jButton2.setFont(font);
```

The `font` class as can be seen from the above link it doesn't include color attribute, unfortunately, but an easy fix, is to declare a global [`Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) object lets say: `Color colorButton = Color.BLUE` that you can later use to set the color to all the buttons.

This becomes useful when you want to change the color of the buttons, you just have to change one line of code, and will affect all the buttons.

### Conclusion

Both solutions may solve your problem, but, in my opinion, implementing your custom class that extends `JButton` is the way to go, as your code will look much clear and straightforward.